# Tensorflow 2.0: How to implement a network with fusion at feature level?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement in tensorflow a small model for a prediction task with two signals as input, that pass individually over a few layers and then are combined in later layers to generate the output prediction. Essentially, the model works like this:

```
(Signal A) -> [L 1] -> [L 2] -> ... -> [L k] 
                                            \
                                             \
                                               -> [L k+1] ->...-> [Final Layer] -> Output
                                             /
                                            /
(Signal B) -> [L 1] -> [L 2] -> ... -> [L k]
```

Where [L i] are different layers of the network. The first part of the network, before fusion, is the same for both signals. What is the proper way to implement this model in tensorflow 2.0? I believe that Sequential is not an option in this scenario, but can I do it through the Functional API or should I go through Model Subclassing? From what I've read, it doesn't seem that both approaches differ that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a template for your model in functional API, you can change the layers according to your needs.

Your base model (common for both) -

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Concatenate, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, GlobalMaxPooling1D, subtract, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1, l2
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

# baseline model

input_shape = (256, 1) # assuming your signals have length 256, 1 channel

# conv base model
sig_input = Input(input_shape)
cnn1 = Conv1D(64,3,activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4))(sig_input)
mp1 = MaxPooling1D()(cnn1)
mp1 = BatchNormalization()(mp1)
cnn2 = Conv1D(128,3,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4))(mp1)
mp2 = MaxPooling1D()(cnn2)
mp2 = BatchNormalization()(mp2)
cnn3 = Conv1D(128,3,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4))(mp2)
mp3 = MaxPooling1D()(cnn3)
mp3 = BatchNormalization()(mp3)
cnn4 = Conv1D(256,3,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4))(mp3)
mp4 = MaxPooling1D()(cnn4)
mp4 = BatchNormalization()(mp4)
flat = Flatten()(mp4)
embed = Dense(64, activation="sigmoid")(flat)

conv_base = Model(sig_input, embed)

conv_base.summary()
```

Network summary:

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         [(None, 256, 1)]          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_12 (Conv1D)           (None, 254, 64)           256       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_12 (MaxPooling (None, 127, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (Batc (None, 127, 64)           256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_13 (Conv1D)           (None, 125, 128)          24704     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_13 (MaxPooling (None, 62, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (Batc (None, 62, 128)           512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_14 (Conv1D)           (None, 60, 128)           49280     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 30, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (Batc (None, 30, 128)           512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_15 (Conv1D)           (None, 28, 256)           98560     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 14, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 14, 256)           1024      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 3584)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 64)                229440    
=================================================================
Total params: 404,544
Trainable params: 403,392
Non-trainable params: 1,152
```

Second fusion network -

```
left_input = Input(input_shape)
right_input = Input(input_shape)

# encode each of the two inputs into a vector with the base conv model
encoded_l = conv_base(left_input)
encoded_r = conv_base(right_input)



fusion = Concatenate()([encoded_l,encoded_r]) # this can be any other fusion method too

prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(fusion)

twin_net = Model([left_input,right_input],prediction)

optimizer = Adam(0.001)

twin_net.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer)

twin_net.summary()
```

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 1)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_8 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 1)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_2 (Model)                 (None, 64)           404544      input_7[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 128)          0           model_2[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_2[2][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            129         concatenate[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 404,673
Trainable params: 403,521
Non-trainable params: 1,152
```

Comment: Great answer! There is one small detail I'd like to understand better, though. For the `conv_base ` you start the model with `sig_input = Input(input_shape)`. Later on, when, when creating the encoded_l and encoded_r, why do you need to create it with `conv_base(Input(input_shape))` ?

Comment: Oh, and another question: how should my input to Model.fit be organized, supposing I'm using a numpy array as input? Currently, my input is a (N, S, V) numpy array, in which N is the number of samples, S is the number of signals, and V is the dimensionality of the signal. How should I reshape it to pass as input to twin_net ?

Comment: In functional API, each time you create a Model instance you need to have at least one Input layer. So, the conv_base is a sub-model or a common model for both signals  but it's a Model so it needs Input, again in the final architecture we design another Model with common conv_base sub Model, so we need Input here too.

Comment: I think that may not be correct, of N = number of samples, S != number of signals, number of samples and number of signals seem same. I think you mean, N = number of samples, S = number of time steps in each signal, V = dimension of signals or the feature at each time steps. If this is your  input shape, you don't need to reshape as this is the exact input numpy array shape that the model wants.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself badly. By sample I meant "training example", I'm used to call them samples but for signals it is a bad choice of words. In a concrete example, I have around 1M training examples (so N = 1M), consisting each of 2 signals (so S = 2), each consisting of 150 features (so V = 150. They are 30s signals sampled at 5Hz). I have that `input_shape = (150, 1)` in this scenario (I use a reshape layer). I tried inputing to the model the (N, S, V) numpy array but got a tensorflow error!

Comment: Oh, I actually got it! I did try splitting my input using `X_ = [X[:, i, :] for i in range(X.shape[1])]` and then passing `X_`to `Model.fit` (since X.shape[1] is the number of signals), but I forgot to do the same for the validation X derp. After fixing it, the network worked!

Comment: @AlbertoA and zabir Can you share the model.fit line of code?  I am getting this error "Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:"